# Typescript class composition generics

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to use class composition in typescript.

```
const FoodMixin = superclass => class extends superclass {
  eat(food) {
    console.log(`Eating ${food}`);
  }
};

class Animal<T> {
  prop: T;
  constructor(public name) {
  }
}

interface Prop {}

class Dog extends FoodMixin(Animal<Prop>) {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args)
  }
}
```

My problem is that I can't pass the generic to the `Animal` class. The following line throws a typescript error:

```
class Dog extends FoodMixin(Animal<Prop>)
```

> expected 1 arguments but got 2

How can I pass generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that when using a function or a constructor as a value you can't specify type parameters.

You could either specify the type parameter explicitly (although this will cause loss of static methods:

```
const FoodMixin = function <T extends new (...arsg: any[]) => any>(superclass: T) {
    return class extends superclass {
        eat(food: string) {
            console.log(`Eating ${food}`);
        }
    };
}
class Animal<T> {
    prop?: T ;
    constructor(public name: string) {
    }
    breathe() : void{}

    static mutate(): void{}
}
class Dog extends FoodMixin<new (name: string) => Animal<Prop>>(Animal) {
    constructor(name: string) {
        super("")
    }
}

var dog = new Dog("");
dog.breathe();
dog.eat("");
dog.prop // is Prop
Dog.mutate // error
```

Or you could create an anonymous class that inherits the corect instantiation of `Animal` and then everything works as expected.

```
class Animal<T> {
    prop?: T ;
    constructor(public name: string) {
    }
    breathe() : void{}

    static mutate(): void{}
}
class Dog extends FoodMixin(class extends Animal<Prop>{}) {
    constructor(name: string) {
        super("")
    }
}

var dog = new Dog("");
dog.breathe();
dog.eat("");
dog.prop // is Prop
Dog.mutate // ok
```